# Are GCP monitoring uptime check metrics suppose to be aggregatable by user labels?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to understand the utility of "user labels" for my uptime checks: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#create

I was expecting it to work like other resources. I want to aggregate the metrics my uptime checks generate by my own custom user labels, but it looks like it doesn't do that?

What's the point of the "user labels" feature?

Answer (score 0):

The [User labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#common-uses) can be used to organize your resource specifically on managing cost-table for a more granular purposes. Other than cost usage their are following uses as below:

- Component labels
- Environment or stage labels
- State labels
- Ownership labels
- Attach key without value

Comment: This is specifically about uptime checks. Their labels don't work for billing data or metrics aggregation. So they cannot be used for cost usage.